# SD Card Reader Error

Tags: drivers, 16.10, acer, sd-card

I'm running Ubuntu 16.10 on an Acer Aspire V5-571P. I'm trying to use the built in card reader to read a micro SD card (that I know is working correctly).

Ubuntu will not recognise the card and I am getting the following message from `dmesg`

```
[11970.123839] mmc0: cannot verify signal voltage switch
[11970.259430] mmc0: tuning execution failed: -22
[11970.259447] mmc0: error -22 whilst initialising SD card
[11971.306468] mmc0: problem reading SD Status register
[11971.722474] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
[11978.487878] mmc0: cannot verify signal voltage switch
[11978.623494] mmc0: tuning execution failed: -22
[11978.623510] mmc0: error -22 whilst initialising SD card
[11979.666515] mmc0: problem reading SD Status register
[11980.082510] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
[11981.126524] mmc0: problem reading SD Status register
[11981.542429] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
```

In case it can help `lsusb` returns:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0489:e04e Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 064e:e330 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f3:0023 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`lsmod | grep sd` returns:

```
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
rtsx_pci               57344  2 rtsx_pci_sdmmc,rtsx_pci_ms
```

and `lspci` returns:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
02:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0a)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

**02:00.0** is my card reader If I'm right.

So all in all I think Ubuntu knows there's a card reader there but cannot read from it ( no drivers? ), anybody know what I have to do to get this working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Internal SD card reader not mounted/detected HP realtek rts5227](http://askubuntu.com/questions/492476/internal-sd-card-reader-not-mounted-detected-hp-realtek-rts5227)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/473848/ubuntu-14-04-realtek-semiconductor-co-ltd-rts5227-pci-express-card-reader-isn

Answer (score 13):

This is going to sound crazy, but assuming you're using a microSD to SD card adatper: try another adapter! I just had this problem with a known good card, and discovered that it worked perfectly with a different SD card adapter. (The "bad" adapter worked correctly with a different microSD card.) I have no idea why this would be, but it was a consistent fix in my case.

Comment: I had this problem too, it actually took trying a few different adapters until I got a working one.

Comment: given the "adapter" that finally worked, was a usb microsd reader, I'm not sure if the adapter was bad or if it was a missing driver in the end but that certainly makes a huge difference.

Comment: Mine works on windows 10 but doesn't work on ubuntu 20.04 (same microsd, same adaptor, same laptop)